# Is there a political faction in Russia publicly advocating for an immediate ceasefire?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Analogous to the corresponding question about [Ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74333/is-there-a-faction-in-the-ukrainian-parliament-favoring-an-immediate-ceasefire):

All the official news coverage I've seen have indicated most of Russia is determined in continued fighting in Ukraine, saying things like that they [will extend territorial claims and are not finished with the war](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/07/20/world/europe/putin-ukraine-invasion-russia-war.html).

Still, the picture might be misleading because Russia can and does suppress opposition quite heavily, not only since the introduction of the law forbidding any criticism of the official position on the war (well you could not legally call it that in Russia). This might hint at that there is a faction within Russia that's in favor of collaborating with Ukraine, and by implication in favor of an immediate ceasefire.

Is there any indication that there is a political faction in Russia (in Parliament or otherwise organized) favoring an immediate ceasefire and publicly advocating it? If not, what about the Russian population at large? As I understand it Russia has criminalized collaboration with Ukraine (which by their definition includes expression of resistance against the war or even calling it as such), hence if such a faction exists I imagine it'll either be underground or among Russian exiles.

I'm referring to Russians who think Russia should implement an immediate ceasefire and say so, but don't identify as Ukrainian (e.g. by taking up Ukrainian citizenship) and will choose to remain Russian afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure if "immediate ceasefire" is a realistic action that Russian leadership could implement - at least as of September 2022 in some areas Ukraine currently was on the offensive and would explicitly not agree to a ceasefire at the status quo frontline, and IIRC that was the case also at July 2022 when this question was originally asked.  A more relevant question would be "is there a political faction in Russia publicly advocating for a withdrawal of Russian troops out of the occupied territories", which is what's required for peace but is very, very different from just a ceasefire.

Comment: @Peteris At the time of writing of the question the situation was different. Tomorrow I will add to this question asking for Russians advocating for a ceasefire and immediate negotiations, possibly including partial withdrawal or complete withdrawal at least to borders from before February or negotiations with that aim. That should realistically present any peace fraction in Russia if it exists.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Alexei Navalny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Navalny) is clearly against continuing the war ([source](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-putin-entertainment-arts-and-europe-1f19bce1209de287834dac097fe6b814)):

> It is now everyone’s duty to make at least some, even the smallest
> contribution to stop this war and remove Putin from power. Protest wherever and however you can. Agitate however you can and whomever you can. Inaction is the worst possible thing. And now its consequence is death.

He is the leader of the [Russia of the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia_of_the_Future) party that is not officially registered.

[Alexei Gorinov](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/jul/08/moscow-councillor-jailed-seven-years-criticising-ukraine-war-alexei-gorinov) has been sentenced for seven years in jail for criticising Russia’s military actions in Ukraine. Wikipedia claims he belongs to [Солидарность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) but I cannot find the official position of this faction towards the war in Ukraine. The faction is against some other wars.

Legal, active factions advocating the cease fire immediately I think are unlikely as they would be banned. Statements against the war are [not allowed](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/03/world/europe/russia-ukraine-propaganda-censorship.html?unlocked_article_code=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACEIPuomT1JKd6J17Vw1cRCfTTMQmqxCdw_PIxftm3iWka3DODm4ZiPsSGYyMvErQf617apwpwi-ARdYELbw1Tf10w6pHJUt1QgahpJeN3Z8IJT4ys5mzX3tw347IWfpw1w7WWVSDCbU1wqyj7VXBOSKsAPaBhWslIgZjp5ozcUX90XFc2qvOQOFqitl6juMrB556RTkDMCKNv6X4Gl4pboX9GxLf6wA8WuFcXjHBz5XLu_9bLlIkWR-RR2h_4G089NpZJNgXWa78JBQrc8b56q4DXi0qdMz6Qs1sGPWH0uliorXPqheTycupxP1QFK1cvrPMtmrSJ08q8UWF5tGb30YlsM_Wnzn7&smid=url-share). Anyone seen to be spreading what the government deems "fakes" about "military action in Ukraine" can earn up to [15](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-60604952) years in jail.

Comment: "Legal, active factions advocating the cease fire immediately I think are unlikely as they would be banned." Interesting. What a strong contrast. In Ukraine, these fraction have their [place in parliament](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74338/8199) and in Russia they are forbidden. But would saying "I want the so-called special military operation to end immediately" in Russia really be punishable? I guess so, but it's not clear on what grounds (although they may just make up some grounds if needed).

Comment: "Everything that’s not propaganda is being eliminated". I have linked the article.

Comment: @Trilarion https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=russians+arrested+against+war

Comment: @Trilarion People have been arrested in Russia for holding up signs reading "`*** *****`" (literally, with asterisks) and even blank pieces of paper.

Comment: Im Russian so yeah - if you are against and protesting, no matter what the law currently says, you will get in jail and after that the best thing that could happen to you is to get free a month later with a couple of bruises and broken bones and a notice from police that your family will be hunted if you try to do that again. Our prisons are not meant to rehabilitate but to completely destroy a human being, so if you get into jail, you either will be out as full fledged criminal or simply dead. That's the holding factor as to why we don't actively protest.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution *In Ukraine, these fraction have their place in parliament* - are you not aware that 11 opposition parties are banned in Ukraine, and Ukranian opposition leaders even arrested, for either opposing the war with Russia and / or objecting to a NATO / EU alliances? [Zelensky Bans Political Opposition, Nationalizes Media to Create ‘Unified’ Information](https://news.antiwar.com/2022/03/20/zelensky-bans-political-opposition-nationalizes-media-to-create-unified-information/).

Answer (score 14):

At least some oligarchs have expressed such an opinion as can be seen in [this Reuters article](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/war-dividing-russian-ukrainian-brothers-billionaire-fridman-says-2022-02-27/) and [this Guardian one](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/27/two-top-russian-billionaires-speak-out-against-invasion-of-ukraine).

Also the [Yabloko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yabloko) party, which is no longer represented in the main parliamentary Duma but is still represented in some local ones, is the main political opposition to the SMO (special military operation) and tried to organize some protests. There is also an [official statement by Yabloko](https://eng.yabloko.ru/the-yabloko-party-considers-the-war-against-ukraine-the-gravest-crime/).

Answer (score 6):

Boris Nadezhdin, who is seeking to run for president, has expressed [anti-war views](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/27/world/europe/russia-putin-election-boris-nadezhdin.html?unlocked_article_code=1.Q00.p5VZ.BP1s94QvzLKN&smid=nytcore-android-share). He told the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68095968), among other things

> "My first task will be to stop the conflict with Ukraine, and then to
> restore normal relations between Russia and the Western community."

Answer (score 3):

From the [electoral program](https://cdn.nadezhdin2024.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0.pdf) of Boris Nadezhdin:

> Россия должна завершить СВО и начать мирные переговоры  
> с Украиной и Западом.

that translates as:

> Russia must end the Special Military Operation and start peace negotiations with Ukraine and the West.

I think this is the call for the immediate cease fire, and also proposing discounts at least somewhat beyond that V. Putin used to offer (more or less to surrender). And also

> Российская Федерация — не осажденная крепость в кольце
> врагов. Переход от противостояния со странами Запада  
> к сотрудничеству. Восстановление отношений и выход  
> из экономической и политической изоляции.

that translates as:

> The Russian Federation is not a besieged fortress surrounded by enemies. Transition from confrontation with Western countries to cooperation. Restoration of relations and exit from economic and political isolation.

Comment: That doesn't call to immediate ceasefire, though. Moreover, it is quite close to the promises that Zelensky was elected for: He was supposed to resolve the Donbass affair and normalize relations with Russia. I'm not even sure how a "ceasefire" can be implemented without the support of the other side.

Comment: Ukraine has prepared peace formula (https://www.parleypolicy.com/post/the-ukrainian-peace-formula-explained). Of course, just asking Zelensky to surrender likely will make  him "not cooperative" but they own document should define the conditions they accept. I do not think that Special Military Operation may be ended  without ceasing fire.

Comment: I don't believe that you understand what a ceasefire means, since in no way does it implies bowing to a list of demands of the other side. Nadezhdin has also, to my knowledge, never said what he things on that peace formula.

Comment: All Russia needs to do is to retreat from the occupied territories and allow Ukraine to join EU as economic union. While Ukraine may want also NATO, reparations, head of Putin and what not, with this much promised Zelensky would have very hard time with his own nation to continue the war.

Comment: Great plan - by the way, are there any signs that Nadezhdin is going to implement it?

Comment: What else? Formally he could also fulfill the promises by defeating Ukraine. This would also end the special military operation and result the ceasefire right as offered. But I am not convinced in this way interpretation of his election program.

Comment: There are a lot of options here, so I would prefer to skip interpretations and only count direct quotes.

Comment: It is not possible to finish the Special Military Operation without ceasing the fire.

Comment: The question is about "immediate" ceasefire, not a ceasefire after talks or any other options. Moreover, I'm not sure presidential candidate is "advocating" for anything. Putting stuff on programme usually means you do not expect anyone else do successfully do the listed stuff, nor do you want anybody else to steal items from your list.

Comment: The part about reparations is where Nadezhdin or even Navalny wouldn't necessarily agree, at least if they wanted power in Russia.

Comment: @alamar there’s a 99% chance Nadezhin doesn’t win the election. But conditional on him winning there’s at least a 10% chance of him pulling off a return to pre-2022 borders.

Comment: @JonathanReez Pff, I would approximate a better chance even with Putin. Putin - 15% of a return to pre-2022 borders, Nadezhdin - 35% Russia crashes and burns.